# Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.ApiController.get_Request()'

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an Azure web app, and when calling a Web API Controller Post method I've been getting the following exception:

`Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageSystem.Web.Http.ApiController.get_Request()'`

I can't reproduce this error when running the app locally, it only happens on Azure.

Here is the controller's code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using TFL.BL;
using TFL.BO;
using TFL.Web.DTO;

namespace TFL.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class SearchController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get() 
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(200);
        }
        // POST: api/Search
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]SearchDTO dto)
        {
            Search s = new Search();
            s.FirstName = dto.FirstName;
            s.LastName = dto.LastName;
            s.Email = dto.Email;
            s.BirthDate = dto.BirthDate;
            s.City = dto.City;
            s.Country = dto.Country;
            s.FromAge = Convert.ToInt32(dto.FromAge);
            s.Gender = Convert.ToInt32(dto.Gender);
            s.ImagePath = dto.ImagePath;
            s.PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dto.PageNumber);
            s.PathUrl = dto.PathUrl;
            s.ProfessionID = Convert.ToInt32(dto.ProfessionID);

            s.State = dto.State;
            s.Str = dto.Str;
            s.Tags = null;
            s.ToAge = Convert.ToInt32(dto.ToAge);
            s.TypeID = Convert.ToInt32(dto.TypeID);
            s.Culture = dto.Culture;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, SearchBL.GetList(s));
        }

        // PUT: api/Search/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Search/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
at TFL.WebAPI.Controllers.SearchController.Post(SearchDTO dto)
↵   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

I can't reproduce this error when running the app locally, it only happens on 
Appreciate any help given!

Comment: can you add the stack trace?

Comment: Sounds like your `System.Web.Http.dll` isn't being copied from local and the one on Azure is outdated.  Make sure that the reference is copied and deployed with the rest of your app.

Comment: What does your API call on the client-side look like?

Comment: something along the lines of `this.http.post(dto)`

Comment: Have you checked whether your GET method of API is worked or not?

Comment: yup, doesn't work as well. BUT - on other controllers it does (for example: http://tfl.azurewebsites.net/api/campaigns)

Comment: After view the link you provided, I saw that it works now. Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by returning an actual object, rather than an HttpResponseMessage.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my side and it worked well on my Azure Web App. Since it worked well on your development machine, please check following option to remove the additional files before publish.

[image]

Comment: I'm actually dragging the DLLs manually to the on-premise bin folder on the kudu SCM console, since I'm having problems simultaneously deploying from GitHub (for my client side angular code) and from Visual Studio (for my service side C# code). Whenever I want to deploy I manually clear the Azure bin folder and copy the files there.

Comment: Please also copy the web.config to your azure web app during publish.

Comment: Please also check whether the URL which you used to request the API is right. It looks like the request hasn't been handled by your Search API. Please also check whether DLL modified date, is it equals to the DLL file at local?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by changing the return type of my web API functions to actual objects, rather then HttpResponseMessages. Works like a charm.

Comment: How do you communicate when something went wrong, e.g. if there are Modelstate errors?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently.  I had to change

```
return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new Error(ModelState, 0)));
```

to

```
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

I still don't know WHY the previous code (which is working in other API projects) messes up here, but this was the fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the web.config file  and was sorted

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Edit your answer and include your comment in your answer.